# Switching between multiple sets of remaps in autohotkey

Tags: key, autohotkey, hotkeys, remap

Basically what I'm trying to do is switch between different keyboard layouts by using different hotkeys.

So when I press

```
^+!F4::
```

these keys are remapped

```
d::Space
f::j
j::k
k::l
```

and doing this

```
^+!F8::
```

will remap

```
a::s
s::d
d::f
f::Space
j::Left
k::Numpad4
l::Numpad5
;::Numpad6
```

and finally

```
^+!F7::
```

Will revert everything to default

Seems whatever I try the script doesn't compile do to duplicate hotkeys. Is this possible to achieve with autohotkey?

Comment: Are you using AutoHotKey_L?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Hotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm) command to change hotkeys dynamically. Here's a small example how you can remap your keys:

```
#Persistent
#UseHook

keyMap := {d: "SPACE", f: "j", j: "k", k: "l"}
; Associative objects are AHK_L only!
; for a pseudo array, do something like this:
; keyMapd := "SPACE"
; keymapf := "j"
; ...

Exit

F4::
    for orig, new in keyMap
    {
        Hotkey, %orig%, RemapKey
    }
return

RemapKey:
    newKey := keyMap[A_ThisHotkey]
    ; to retrieve from a pseudo array, do this:
    ; newKey := keyMap%A_ThisHotkey%
    Send, {%newKey%}
return
```

`keyMap`is an associative array, mapping the original key with its new target. Pressing `F4` will take every key defined in `keyMap` and assign it a subroutine called `RemapKey`, hence it will be called, when any key in `keyMap` (**d**, **f**, **j** or **k**) is pressed. `RemapKey` takes the latest hotkey by accessing `A_ThisHotkey`, finds out what it's mapped to and sends that key.  The `#UseHook` is essential in order to prevent the `Send` command to trigger another hotkey (in our case, pressing ****F would trigger **J**, **J** would then trigger **K** and so on).
Note, that the use of associative objects if **AutoHotkey_L only**. If you're using another version, you'll have to define your map another way (e.g. a pseudo array like `keyMapd:="SPACE"`).

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative way, also requiring AutoHotKey_L.

```
#SingleInstance Force
Flag:=0
Return

^+!F7::
Flag:=0
TrayTip, AutoHotKey, Keyboard setting Default, 1
Return

^+!F4::
Flag:=1
TrayTip, AutoHotKey, Keyboard setting A, 1
Return

^+!F8::
Flag:=2
TrayTip, AutoHotKey, Keyboard setting B, 1
Return

#If (Flag=1)
x::SoundBeep, 500, 100
d::Space
f::j
j::k
k::l
#If

#If (Flag=2)
x::SoundBeep, 2000, 100
a::s
s::d
d::f
f::Space
j::Left
k::Numpad4
l::Numpad5
;::Numpad6
#If
```